# Should I use 'other' or 'others' as an option item?

Tags: grammatical-number

I am going to make a list of options. Which the correct form to use as an option: 'other' or 'others'? The option may contain several members.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No matter if the option contains one or several members, the term to use is

***other***.

Firstly, this is the term most commonly used.

Also, the reason seems to be that the word 'other' here is not a noun but an adjective: it does not refer to 'the other' but the set of 'other options'. As *other* is not a noun here, it cannot be pluralized.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you are asking.

> How do you travel most of the journey to work?  [Choose one]
>    • car
>    • bike
>    • train
>    • walk
>    • other [Specify ....................................]
>
> Which two modes of transport do you use most on the journey to work? [Choose two]
>    • car
>    • bike
>    • train
>    • walk
>    • other  [Specify ....................................]

What is your requirement? If two other unlisted modes of transport should be entered in the last choice (say helicopter and skateboard), then that could say *Others*, which would indicate that more than one can be entered.

> • others [Specify ....................................]

On the other hand, if you want each of the "other" choices to be specified separately, it would be better to indicate that:

> • other  [Specify ....................................]
>    • other  [Specify ....................................]